# NO_PUBKEY and Some of The File Has an Unsupported Filetype

Tags: updates, mysql, repository

When I do a command "sudo apt update" on Ubuntu 22.04.3, always occure this error :

```
W: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Delete the `mysql.list` then reinstall it.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.29-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.29-1_all.deb
```

---

After the deprecation of `apt-key`, you can't use the old repository format, that's why you have received a lot of warning. (old keyring set in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/). The new keyring should be downloaded in `/etc/apt/keyrings` or in `/usr/share/keyrings`. By downloading and installing the `mysql-apt-config_0.8.29-1_all.deb` the `mysql` repository will be set correctly.

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools-preview
```

The gpg key is included in the `.deb` file (the `postinst` script), it should be placed later under `/usr/share/keyrings/`.

[Read more about third party repository on Ubutnu help.](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/third-party-apt-repositories)